# Display Hexadecimal Digits

Tags: c++

How would I display hexadecimal digits or decimal, based on the user's input at the command line using. Prompt the user to input a character.

```
void output_hex(char ch)
{
    std::cout << std::hex << int(ch);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string str("hello");
    std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), output_hex);
    return 0;
}
```

so far this is what I got.

Comment: 1.  What does this code output?  2.  What would you like it to output?

Comment: The code right here I believe should input text into a console and have it convert and display the hexadecimal.
I would like it to output hexadecimal digits based on the users input.

Comment: Then `std::string str{}; std::cout << "enter a string: "; if (getline (std::cin, str)) std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), output_hex);` Add a `std::cout.put('\n');` at the end to make your program POSIX compliant.

Comment: You can eliminate the `output_hex()` function just by using a lamba function, e.g. `std::for_each (str.begin(), str.end(), [](int c) { std::cout << std::hex << c;} );`

Comment: So the question should be how do I input a line of text from a user into a `std::string` and have nothing to do with hex since you know how to do that part?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it, but I recommend to use [the function `printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/?kw=printf) if you are going to insert variables into a text.

```
// #include <stdio.h>      // For printf()
#include <iostream>        // For std::cout

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    
    for (int c = 1; c < argc; c++){
        for (int i = 0; argv[c][i] != '\0'; i++){
            // printf("'%c' -> %X \n", argv[c][i], argv[c][i]);  // Clasic style
            std::cout << "'" << argv[c][i] << "' -> " <<     
            std::hex << argv[c][i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Alex, while that will output the character and hex value if the question were tagged C, the question here is "How do I take user input and then output as is already shown in the question?" No dings, but you want to avoid mixing C answers in questions tagged C++.

Comment: Yea, the i got the idea that the title was the problem and the description what he was trying to do, but still, the std libs are not exactly c, they contain c++ specific implementations, it's is like windows.h, a c and c++ file, printf() seems better for this case.

Comment: For this program that just uses the standard library and is a console applicaton you need not include `windows.h`. You only need that if the program needs to access the windows API directly.